# Зацикливается событие нажатии кнопки

Tags: javascript, ajax

Есть страница, куда с помощью `ajax` запроса вставляются данные. Вот кусочек кода:

```
foreach ($sql_object as $ps){ $i++; ?>
<div id="<?= $i?>" class="getApiId">...</div>}
```

Сначала вывожу список циклом. После этого, по нажатию на блок, беру у блока `data-api`

```
$('.getApiId').on('click', function() { //Показать поставщика
    var url = '...';
    var api_id = $(this).attr('data-api');
    var data = {...};
    async_query(url,data);
});

function async_query(url,data) {
    $.ajax({
        url:url,
        type:'POST',
        data:data,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(html){
            if(this_show != 0)
            {
                $('...').html(html).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Проблема в том что код зацикливается, т.е. когда выбираю элемент из списка первый раз, то все норм, а когда второй, третий раз... Получаю кучу событий нажатий на кнопку, которые увеличиваются в два раза каждый раз. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Код

```
$('.getApiId').on('click', ...
```

выполняется многократно.

Замените его на

```
$(document).on("click", ".getApiId", function () { ...
```

и вызывайте **только один раз** в `$(document).ready(function(){ ... });`.

Comment: Это не сработало. P.S. обработчик события уже находится в `$(function(){...`

Comment: @r.mcreal Что находится в переменной `html`, которая подается в `success`?